# Split contents of a Python dataframe into new columns

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a Python dataframe with a column containing values in the following format: numbers/numbers-letter-numbers. Example: 2/39-C-19. I would like to take the values in this column and split them and assign them to new columns within my dataframe.

I tried some regular expressions, though I haven't found a good way to exclude the dataframe index. The regex '(?:\d*.)?\d+' gives me all of the numbers in the column including the index.

So, this is an example of my raw data from my dataframe:

```
LOCATION
0  2/39-C-19
1   130/3-A-09
2   1/1-B-11
3   22/5-B-16
4   1/4-A-24
```

I am trying to come up with a good way to parse the values so I have multiple columns like this:

```
    Number1 Number2 Letter  Number3
2   39  C   19
130 3   A   9
1   1   B   11
22  5   B   16
1   4   A   24
```

Here is code I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
raw_data = 'file.csv'
raw_data_df = pd.read_csv(raw_data)
location_df = raw_data_df.iloc[:,[1]]
location_string = str(location_df)
re_location = re.findall('(?:\d*\.)?\d+', location_string)
print(re_location)
```

Any thoughts on how best to go about this? I'm wondering if I don't need regular expressions after all and maybe need to create a loop to iterate through values in the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [97]: cols = 'Number1 Number2 Letter  Number3'.split()

In [98]: df[cols] = df.LOCATION.str.extract(r'(\d+)/(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)', expand=True)

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
     LOCATION Number1 Number2 Letter Number3
0   2/39-C-19       2      39      C      19
1  130/3-A-09     130       3      A      09
2    1/1-B-11       1       1      B      11
3   22/5-B-16      22       5      B      16
4    1/4-A-24       1       4      A      24
```

or

```
In [107]: df.LOCATION.str.split(pat=r'[/-]', expand=True)
Out[107]:
     0   1  2   3
0    2  39  C  19
1  130   3  A  09
2    1   1  B  11
3   22   5  B  16
4    1   4  A  24
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I wonder: could a similar approach be used to split a df column containing last name, first name, initials (Ex1: Smith, John Ex2: Doe, Jane S) ? The tried the following approach, which worked well for names containing last name, first name, and middle initial, though NaN appeared for names with only last name and first name. Is there a good way to account for the optional middle initial? cols2 = 'Last_name First_name Middle'.split()
name_df[cols2] = name_df.NAME.str.extract(r'(\w+),(\w+) (\w+)', expand=True)

Comment: @mmmgood, yeah, we can do that, but think of [names containing several words](https://www.google.de/amp/www.sheknows.com/parenting/articles/825167/top-double-baby-names-for-girls-and-boys/amp)

Comment: there's probably a more efficient regex, to split the name column, but I came up with the following: r'(\w+?\s?\w+),(\s?\w+\-?\w+)(\s?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?)'

Answer (score 0):

I will leave it up to you as far as the implementation into your dataframe, but this should provide a simple means of splitting your location strings into multiple items:

```
import re

s = ['2/39-C-19', '130/3-A-09', '1/1-B-11', '22/5-B-16', '1/4-A-24']

for i in s:
    s_new = re.split(r'[/-]',i)
    print(s_new)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['2', '39', 'C', '19']
['130', '3', 'A', '09']
['1', '1', 'B', '11']
['22', '5', 'B', '16']
['1', '4', 'A', '24']
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty new to re. So, it looks like the split method is splitting on / and - characters in this case. This will be good notation for me to remember in the future.

Comment: You bet. And yes, this regex is splitting on both '/' and '-' by using character classes. I would recommend the following videos if you want some exposure to regular expressions, these helped me a ton: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DG3kCDx53c